# No Wi-Fi connectivity under Windows 10 on my Boot Camped MacBook

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mac, connection, windows-10

It can't connect to Wi-Fi at all. I can't even see a Wi-Fi option. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your wireless card drivers are probably not working. See if there are updates available for Windows 10 or try rolling back/uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your WiFi drivers are outdated. Because you are using apple provided drivers, you should have looked up if windows 10 is already supported. Apples homepage shows that:

> Boot Camp 5.1 supports 64-bit, non-Enterprise versions of Windows 7, Windows 8.0, and Windows 8.1. This version of Boot Camp doesn't support Windows XP, Windows Vista, or any 32-bit version of Windows.

they don't mention windows 10, they don't say it's supported. if you do have outdated drivers, you could (and you should have) tried the latest boot camp drivers. Nobody from us can help you here. You have to wait until apple releases the new bootcamp drivers.

Comment: This is probably it. I'd add that there's a chance he could find Windows 10 compatible drivers from the vendor of the Wi-Fi chipset in his Mac (probably Broadcom, although some older Macs used Atheros, which is now part of Qualcomm).